# Why For isValid upon invalid phone number?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple validation:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const form = document.getElementById("test");
 if(!form.checkValidity()){
   alert("Error");
 } else {
   alert("ok");
 }
});
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="user@example.com" />
  <input type="tel" name="tel" value="excalibur" />
</form>
```

But despite `excalibur` not being a valid phone number still `checkValidity` returns value as valid. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: Telephone numbers are not validated by the browser (unless you write your own validation code).